How can I get pydoit to re-build task dependencies only as needed?
I have tasks to build a dataset, and to process that dataset. I have them set up as a task graph with doit. process_dataset depends on the targets of build_dataset. I want to iterate on these two pieces independently.
If I run doit run process_dataset it will always run build_dataset, even if those targets already exist.
If I run doit run -s process_dataset it will only do the processing part, reusing the existing dataset files. However, if those files aren't present, I get an error. I must manually run build_dataset first.
What I want is to run doit run -s process_dataset and have doit automatically regenerate the dependencies (using the build_dataset task) only if they are not present. Is there an easy way to do that?
